# Wordpress Contact Form 7 do not work with wpml when site has ?lang=en

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Nothing happens when I submit the form.

I get this error in the console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I can see something suspicious on the post URL.

/wp-json/?lang=en/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/11187/feedback

for some reason GET variable ?lang=en ends upp in the url. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://wpml.org/errata/contact-form-7-secondary-language-form-submission-fails/) page, you can solve this issue by adding the following line inside the *functions.php*:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be arise due to URL structure, you can change it by following steps:

1. Go to **WPML** > **Languages** > **Language URL format**
2. Use "*Directories structure*" (**Different languages in directories**) instead of "*language name added as a parameter*".

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

I had resolved the issue by adding following code in the function.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_footer_scripts',100 );
function my_footer_scripts()
{
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   wpcf7.apiSettings.root = wpcf7.apiSettings.root.replace("/?lang=en","");
 </script>
<?php
}
```

You can replace "**/?lang=en**" as per your need.

I hope this will help someone.